# how to make tiktok downloader without watermark php

Tags: php, tiktok, jdownloader

I want to make tiktok downloader php. I heard from some articles stackoverflow that tiktok has two version of videos (watermarked and original). I want that my web can download the original without watermark.

I have tried some github repositories like this https://github.com/TufayelLUS/TikTok-Video-Downloader-PHP. But it only work for video that uploaded before July 27th, 2020. Can you guys give me a help like suggestion for this?

Comment: First you need to find TikTok's API. As far as I can tell, they didn't publish one, so you should go over unofficial APIs and implementations and check if someone has original videos for downlonad. Although I doubt it.

Comment: Anyone resolve the video without watermark problem?

Answer (score 1):

Tiktok not provide any official api for fetch video data, So you have to download it by using curl scrap methods or you can use npm package in node js.